# How to customise maximum login attempt attribut in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I'm implementing a security mecanism in a asp.net application , eventually I'm thinking about using this property

[PasswordAttemptWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.passwordattemptwindow(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
  <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" 
  userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <add name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="SqlServices"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
      passwordAttemptWindow="30"
      applicationName="MyApplication" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

But if I would like to make something  that will increment the waiting delay from the previous attempts ,is there any way to do it ?

Example :  if a user try 5 wrong password for the first time , the account should be locked to 1 min , but after that min if he still enter 5 other wrong passwords the delay should increase to 5 min and so on

Thank you

Comment: I don't think so, not out of the box anyway. Although I'd question if it matters? This is all to prevent brute force, so does a rolling window really matter? My logic is that even if you find something that works, will it be stable or will it cause more headaches  than it saves in the future.

Comment: @Joe_DM You guessed it right , yes it's eventually to reduce brute force effectiveness ( we all know that brute force cannot be stopped 100%) The reason is I'm building an application for a school project , eventually the professor will come at some point and run script as to guess the passwords , and it explains why I'm looking around to maximize login security

Comment: @napi15: a more correct way of preventing bruteforce attacks is to activate a captcha after, say, 3 failed login attempts. Assuming you have a strong captcha, auto probing is no longer possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

Configure in you database some columns where you want to stores value

**Second**

```
  maxInvalidPasswordAttempts=YourDBValue

  passwordAttemptWindow=YourDBValue
```

of course you should implement elswhere a mecanism where you have to let the admin be able to save the data inside those columns